# move_uploaded_file won't work?

Tags: php

I got a serious problem for some reasons,
My function move_uploaded_file won't work, and don't return an error (surrounded by a try catch, and no error in phplog)

I already visit a lot of google links about that, didn't saw anything that could help me, debugged all lines of the code, and can't see any errors.. So I go to you, if you could hellp me !

Thanks a lot!!

```
if(isset($_FILES['avatar']) && !empty($_FILES['avatar']['name']))
        {
            $maxSize = 512000; // 50 Ko
            $validesExt = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png'); // Only jpg, jpeg or png

            if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] <= $maxSize)
            {
                $extUpload = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['avatar']['name'], '.'), 1)); // Get extension
                if(in_array($extUpload, $validesExt))
                {
                    $path = asset('boostpanel_assets/img/avatars/' . $_SESSION['user']['id'].".".$extUpload); // Upload the avatar
                    try {
                        $dep = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $path); // move the file to the folder
                        if ($dep) {
                            $db->update('users', $_SESSION['user']['id'], 'id', [
                                'avatar' => $_SESSION['user']['id']
                            ]);
                        }
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        die($e->getMessage());
                        $status = 'error';
                        $message = 'Oops! Something went wrong.';
                        return $this->redirect->route('profile')->with($status, $message);
                    }
                }else{
                    $status = 'error';
                    $message = 'This extension is not valid, only jpg, jpeg or png';
                    return $this->redirect->route('profile')->with($status, $message);
                }
            }else{
                $status = 'error';
                $message = 'Your avatar is too big.';
                return $this->redirect->route('profile')->with($status, $message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: you have `die($e->getMessage());` before the rest of your error reporting code. By doing that the rest of your code will not work since you already used `die`. A possible debug check for `move_uploaded_file` is to make sure the file permissions for your path is set correctly 775

Comment: Change `die($e->getMessage());` to this `$status = '$e->getMessage()';` remove die

Comment: In `$_FILES` there's an element with key` 'error'`, you should check it. And what does asset(..) function do? Make sure it's returning a valid directory path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the issue by looking the doc!
For everyone who need : move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path) : $path need to be a relative path, and not the absolute path.

My function asset() was returning the absolute path.

Thanks.